# Lagrangian rotation torque - How to describe that?

Tags: trigonometry, rotations, classical-mechanics

Lagrangian mechanics is about to sum all the Potential energy and Kinectic energy:

$$ L = \sum_{i=1}^n(KE_i - PE_i)$$

Let's say that we have a rotating arm:

[image]

With the length $A$, mass $M$ and angle $B$.

Lagrangian equation for this is:

$$L = KE_1 - PE_1 = J\dot{B}^2 - MgA\sin(B)$$

And intertia $J$ is:

$$ J = M((L\sin B)^2 + (L\cos B)^2) = ML^2 $$

Due to:

$$ 1 = \sin^2 B + \cos^2 B \forall B$$

And finally:

$$L = ML^2\dot{B}^2 - MgA\sin B$$

But how would it be if I added a torque $T$ here:

[image]

Would the Lagrangian equation be rewritten like this then:

$$L = ML^2(\dot{B} - \dot{T})^2 - MgA\sin B$$

If the $\dot{B} = \dot{T}$ then the whole system will be static and only have potential energy conserved.

Or am I wrong? Will it be like this:

$$L = ML^2(\dot{B}^2 - \dot{T}^2) - MgA\sin B$$

Comment: But what I have learnt about Lagrangian mechanics is that the Lagrangian is kinetic energy minus potential energy. Adding is Hamiltonian.

Comment: Yes! Sorry! I will change the question. Thanks for the notation.

Comment: Search "lagrangian mechanics external force" on Google for a general answer

Comment: @edm  Well...that means I can just add the forces after this equation: $$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}})- \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = Q_{Force}$$ because this: $$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}})- \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0 = N$$ is the newtonian system. With the forces $Q_{Force}$ it will be: $$N = Q_{Force}$$

Comment: I thought that I can add the forces here $$L = KE_i - PE_i + Force_i$$

Comment: @edm Can I not say that my torque force $T$ will be $$E_{Potential} = \frac{1}{2}J \theta^2 $$ due to the kinect rotation energy is:$$E_{Kinect} = \frac{1}{2}J \dot{\theta} ^2 $$  ??? Potential energy for draging out a spring is: $$E_{Potential} = \frac{1}{2}mx^2$$ while the kinect energy is: $$E_{Kinect} = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2$$